# Extension of Definition of Concavity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

**Question**

Suppose that the graph of a function $f$ is concave up on an open interval $I$. Show that, for any $a, b \in I$, where $a < b$ and $0 < \lambda < 1$, $$(1 - \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) > f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b).$$

---

**My working**

From the definition of a function being concave up, $$f(b) - f(a) > (b - a)f'(a).$$

When $b = (1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b$,

$$f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b) - f(a) > ((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b - a)f'(a)$$

$$\implies f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b) - f(a) > \lambda (b - a)f'(a)$$

---

This is where I am currently stuck at. I have a hunch that I am supposed to use the definition once more by substituting another set of values for $b$ and $a$ in order to get rid of the $f'(a)$, but I cannot see what they are. Any intuitions will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your first inequality is how (strict) convexity is [*defined.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition)

Comment: Yes, it is! May I know if there is a problem with using that?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand your question. $(1 - \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) > f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b)$ is how a (strict) concave up (aka strict convex) function is *defined,* so you cannot *show* that. – What exactly is your definition of “concave up”?

Comment: $f(b) − f(a) > (b − a)f′(a)$ is *not* the generic definition. The generic definition is $(1 - \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) > f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b)$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Definition.

Comment: Oh. I understand what you are trying to say now. Okay my bad. Allow me to rephrase then. How do I get from my definition (as stated in the post) to the generic definition. Is it possible?

Comment: That is simple: Set $c= (1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b$ and then apply your definition to $f(a)-f(c)$ and to $f(b) - f(c)$.

Comment: It should yield the same result if I take $f(c) - f(a)$ and $f(c) - f(b)$ instead right?

Comment: The idea is to estimate both $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ in terms of $f(c)$ and $f'(c)$. Then the desired inequality follows easily.

Comment: Oh I see. So that is why you replace $a$ by $c$, in order to get $f’(c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function $f: I \to \Bbb R$ is strictly convex (aka strictly “concave up”) if
$$ \tag 1
f((1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b) < (1 - \lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b)
$$
for all $a, b \in I$ with $a \ne b$ and all $\lambda \in (0, 1)$. For a *differentiable* function this is equivalent to
$$ \tag 2
f(y) - f(x) > (y - x)f'(x)
$$
for all $x, y \in I$ with $x \ne y$.

To see that $(2)$ implies $(1)$, set $c = (1 - \lambda)a + \lambda b$. Then
$$
\begin{align}
 f(a)  &> f(c) + (a-c) f'(c) = f(c) + \lambda (a-b) f'(c) \\
 f(b) &> f(c) +(b-c) f'(c) = f(c) +(1-\lambda) (b-a) f'(c) 
\end{align}
$$
and therefore
$$ 
(1-\lambda)f(a) + \lambda f(b) > (1-\lambda)f(c) + \lambda f(c) = f(c) \, .
$$

Comment: Nice proof ! (+1)